# Extjs Grid Panel выделить несколько строк

Tags: extjs

На **Extjs Grid Panel** надо  выделить несколько строк и отправить **Ajax**-ом.

Умею отправлять по одному.

Подскажите, как реализовать выделение нескольких строк?

Надо отслеживать нажатие **Ctrl** или есть другие способы?

Answer (score 3):

При создании `Ext.grid.Panel` вам нужно переопределить создание `selModel`.
К примеру в конструкторе панели вы определяете

```
createSelModel: function() {
    var me = this;
    if (me.mode === 'SINGLE') me.mode = 'SINGL';
    me.objs.selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.RowModel', {
        mode: me.mode
    });
},
```

в конфиге компонента `selModel` вы можете выбрать `mode : "SINGLE"/"SIMPLE"/"MULTI"`. В вашем случае нужен `"MULTI"`. Подробнее читайте здесь:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model